# Typescript not recognizing if-statement-function-call in type-check

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found this issue in typescript. I have following example:

```
type AirplaneDTO = {
    color?: string|null
    owner?: string|null
}

type Airplane = {
    color: string
    owner: string
}

function isValidAirplane(airplane: AirplaneDTO): boolean {
    return !!(airplane.color && airplane.owner);
}

function getValidAirplane(airplane: AirplaneDTO): Airplane|undefined {
    if (!isValidAirplane(airplane)) {
        return;
    }
    return {
        color: airplane.color,
        owner: airplane.owner,
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am converting data from AirplaneDTO to Airplane. I don't want to set Airplane object if some of the fields in AirplaneDTO are null or undefined.

As I am doing this check if all the fields inside are set, TS does not recognize the "isValidAirplane" function-call and gives me following Error: `Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)`

You can try my code and Error here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgglgJzAGwIYDsIBEAqB5KAXigG8AoKSqAYwHtlaEB+ALigGdgE50BzAH3QBXZMgpVaAd0zM2nbn0EixAXzJlQkWIhQZoxclRr1Gcrj17jKUmWYWW1ZAGZD01YHFroocdgDVUZDgAE3gkNEwAClQdCIg2MN1MXDwASjYAI1p6CAxSKygECGAhBG8AQnLo2L0AOjoGBCgAMmaoGPC6mwgEVIBuMkcXNw8vKF5igKDQmqiOpPjtTuT8dKWF-ldgiCceCGD8ozgnKEjy3ymQxLjq5YhU1MOjKiKSsoGjNSNX0u9DZ8oDVM7VmEHqJgQABoCkZugg2PM4rU4dDPupHOogA

Is this an known Typescript issue or did I do something wrong here?

Comment: If it's already a valid "Airplane", why not return it instead of `undefined`?

Comment: You're close, just make `isValidAirplane` a type predicate by changing the return type from `boolean` to `airplane is Airplane`. [More here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: Just FWIW, you don't need to create a new object in `getValidAirplane` if you don't want to. You know the object that was passed in is a valid `Airplane` after the `isValidAirplane` call, so you could just return it.

Comment: @Pointy its not a valid Airplane if one of the fields inside are null or undefined.

Comment: @MarkusB - [Here's your playground updated with the change I mentioned above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgglgJzAGwIYDsIBEAqB5KAXigG8AoKSqAYwHtlaEB+ALigGdgE50BzAH3QBXZMgpVaAd0zM2nbn0EixAXzJlQkWIhQZoxclRr1Gcrj17jKUmWYWW1ZAGZD01YHFroocdgDVUZDgAE3gkNEwAClQdCIg2MN1MXDwASjYY8L0fdm0szFIrKAQIYCEEbwBCSujYvQA6OgYEKAAyVqhMpIh6mwgEVIBuMkcXNw8vKF5SgKDQuqiuuISF7Hx0vO7+V2CIJx4IYMKjOCcoSMrfWZDEuNr8iFTU46MqErKK4aM1I3fy70Mr0oTVMnVWjRMCAANEUjH0EBlwfCYd91I51EA).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to [parse, not validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/).

Thus instead of `isValidAirplane` you have the following function:

```
function parseAirplane(airplane: AirplaneDTO): Airplane | undefined {
    const { color, owner } = airplane
    if (color && owner) {
      return { color, owner }
    }
}
```

Instead of returning `undefined`, you can also return an `Error` type...

Comment: I don't agree; the word "parse" really means (or, *should* mean) to extract structure from plain text. Also, either "color" or "owner" could be empty in a valid airplane, for all we know.

Comment: @Pointy did you read the linked article? (and according to OPs type definitions, a valid `Airplane` has no optional fields...

Comment: This is very nice with just two parameters to check. but if there are much more fields and checks I want to make instead of if (color && owner) I want to extract it in an own function... And this is my problem, that TS doesn't recognize that.